# How to test a patch request in Django Rest Framework?

Tags: python, django, unit-testing, django-rest-framework

I have two test cases in Django Rest Framework: One is a post and one is a patch testcase. The post works without a problem, but the patch trows a problem. In reality they both work.

```
with open(os.path.join(self.path, "..", "..", "plugin/test_files/icons.png"), 'rb') as file_obj:
    document = SimpleUploadedFile(
        file_obj.name, file_obj.read(), content_type='image/png')

    re = self.patch(f"/api/units/{unit_id}/",
                    {"files": [document]}, content_type=MULTIPART_CONTENT)
    self.assertIn('pictures', re)
    self.assertEqual(len(re["pictures"]), 1)  # Fails with 0 != 1

with open(os.path.join(self.path, "..", "..", "plugin/test_files/icons.png"), 'rb') as file_obj:
    document = SimpleUploadedFile(
        file_obj.name, file_obj.read(), content_type='image/png')
    re = self.post("/api/units/",
                    {"company_id": 1, "name": "test",
                    "address_id": 1, "files": [document]}, content_type=MULTIPART_CONTENT)
    self.assertIn('pictures', re)
    self.assertEqual(len(re["pictures"]), 1)
```

My views are in both cases the default UpdateMixin and CreateMixin, the serializer is the same. It appears that there is no `request.data` on the patch request. How can I achieve my data actually arriving in the backend here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out that the content needs to be encoded for all requests other than POSTs. This would be the adjusted testing code:

```
with open(os.path.join(self.path, "..", "..", "plugin/test_files/icons.png"), 'rb') as file_obj:
    document = SimpleUploadedFile(file_obj.name, file_obj.read(), content_type='image/png')

    encoded_data = encode_multipart(data={"files": [document]}, boundary=BOUNDARY)
    re = self.patch(f"/api/units/{unit_id}/", encoded_data, format='multipart', content_type=MULTIPART_CONTENT)
self.assertIn('pictures', re)
self.assertEqual(len(re["pictures"]), 1)
```

Answer (score 0):

The issue here may be with the way you are sending the data in the patch request. When sending data with a patch request, it is important to ensure that the data is sent in the correct format. In your case, it looks like you are sending the file data in the form of a SimpleUploadedFile object. However, sending a file object directly as data in a patch request is not supported by DRF.

Instead, you should encode the file object into a base64 string before sending it in the patch request. You can use the base64 module for this purpose. Once the file object is encoded, you can send it as a string in the patch request. This should ensure that the data gets properly received in the backend.

Here is an example of how to encode a file object into a base64 string and send it in the patch request:

```
import base64

with open(os.path.join(self.path, "..", "..", "plugin/test_files/icons.png"), 'rb') as file_obj:
    document = base64.b64encode(file_obj.read())

re = self.patch(f"/api/units/{unit_id}/",
                {"files": [document]}, content_type=MULTIPART_CONTENT)
self.assertIn('pictures', re)
self.assertEqual(len(re["pictures"]), 1)
```

Comment: This is false I suppose, as the POST works and doesn't need this encoding. Also I tested it and it doesn't work.